# Using git-bash as integrated terminal in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, git-bash

Git bash integrates well into VS Code but not Visual studio. In VS Code, it opens in the terminal tab but in Visual Studio (17.4.2), it opens as a separate window.
Is there a way I can get git bash to open as an integrated terminal, just like Developer Powershell?

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't reproduce this problem. git-bash runs in the terminal tab as expected.

What I did:

1. From the menu choose Tools -> Options
2. In the Options dialog choose Environment -> Terminal
3. Add a new Profile with

   - Name: `Git Bash`
   - Shell Location: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`
   - Arguments: `-i -l`

The terminal in Visual Studio is based on the Windows Terminal. I used the 'Git Bash' profile in Windows Terminal as the template for the profile in Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you. This works. I was linking to `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` and that causes it to start separately. I am able to get an integrated terminal with your solution.

Comment: thanks, bash.exe is under  C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe